# Is there a word for an agreement between two businesses to send customers each other's way?

Tags: single-word-requests

Say you have two businesses, A and B, which serve nearly the same target market.

A and B make an agreement than in the cases in which the customer is not an exact fit for their business, they will redirect the customer to the other business.

Is there a specific word that refers to such a partnership?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean, it looks like you are referring to affiliated companies. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/affiliated

Comment: An [affiliate agreement](https://www.rocketlawyer.com/gb/en/quick-guides/affiliate-agreements) is often one-sided (e.g. A sends B customers and B pays A in return, but B does not send A customers). So it's not an exact match. But that doesn't mean a better answer exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Businesses might have a **reciprocal agreement**. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/reciprocal-agreement) has

> **reciprocal**
> <sub>ADJECTIVE</sub>
>
> A reciprocal action or agreement involves two people or groups who do the same thing to each other or agree to help each another in a similar way.
>
> *Members also have access to a portfolio of 200 luxury properties through reciprocal agreements with other organisations.*

An example of such an arrangement might be two hotels, who direct customers they cannot accommodate to the other hotel, as their recommendation.

Comment: As the quoted definition itself shows, this is a much broader term than what the OP has in mind: the OP is seeking a term for an agreement about a very **specific** kind of mutual help.

Comment: @jsw29 is right - I was curious if there is a term that captures the specific scenario that I described.

Answer (score 2):

"Collusion", if the two companies are rivals in the same industry space and the author wanted to convey such actions as having negative impact on the industry space. Take the rivalry between Apple and Microsoft - both tech giants who control quite a sizable piece of the tech market. If the two companies were to cooperate with each other in the aforementioned way (send customers each other's way), then perhaps a good word would be "*collusion*".

(["In the study of economics and market competition, collusion takes place within an industry when rival companies cooperate for their mutual benefit." - Wikipedia, entry on "Collusion"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collusion))

Usually "collusion" carries the implication that the rivals referred to are cooperating to suppress other competitors and monopolize whatever industry they happen to be in.

However, if the writer simply wanted to convey neutral or positive connotations towards these actions, they might use the term already suggested by kind answerer Weather Vane, aka "reciprocal agreement". They do a very good job of explaining this term accurately and concisely, so I'll omit my explanation instead.

TL;DR "collusion" (negative), "reciprocal agreement" (neutral/positive)

Answer (score -3):

Such an arrangement may be a type of **cartel**. Cartels are designed to improve business profitability, often by fixing prices in a group of companies.

But there are many types of cartel, and the third type (according to the following site) is:

> [WallStreetMojo](https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/cartel/#h-types-of-cartels)
> Customer Assignment Cartels – Specific customers are assigned to each member. Thus, all customers are divided amongst the members to ensure a proper flow of revenue
> . Each member shall maintain the dignity of allocation and must not fetch customers of the other members
> {see picture below}

Hence, the arrangement you describe might be a form of cartel if, for example, the customer allocation agreement is made secretly to the exclusion of other companies.

[image]

Comment: A company within a cartel does not “redirect” customers to other companies in the  cartel.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is a gross simplification of what constitutes a cartel and it is not even attempting to make a connection between the question and the WallStreetMojo-Sources (...) direct quote. There are technical terms that have a precise meaning and we should not just use any word for anything that "might" have a slight resemblance.

Comment: @SebastianE Did my use of "may be" and "might" not register with you in your haste to be "grossly" condemnatory? Answers are a contribution to questioners, and are not necessarily or even desirably a complete discussion of all possibilities.

Comment: I even quoted your "might". The problem is that you did not describe the circumstances in which it "might" be a cartel. Certainly not in the circumstances described in the question, so you should add some detail to your answer.

Comment: @SebastianE A helpful suggestion, so  I have edited to make clear at least one circumstance in which the arrangement could be part of a cartel.